# When should the "lists" tag be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

So far there is no usage guidance for the tag [lists](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists). According Wikipedia, [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)) may refer to an abstract data type, or a concrete data structure [linked-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

So when should we use the tag [lists](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists)?

I thought it should be used only for the abstract data type meaning because there is already a [linked-lists](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-lists) tag.

Comment: What exactly prompts your question? It seems clear that, yes, [tag:lists] is to be used on all data structure questions than handle lists, be they linked lists, skip lists, or jump lists.

Comment: @Raphael Sometimes I tag a question about linked lists, I don't know which one to choose. If I choose both, it seems a bit verbose.

Comment: Ah, that's the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl;dr: Both is fine!

---

We have different levels of tags: some, like [complexity-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity-theory), cover entire fields of research; others, like [rice-theorem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rice-theorem), relate to a very specific thing.

The [idea](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/814/98) is to always have a little of everything: "big" tags to broadly classify the question, and then as many and as specific tags as you can fit in the limit of five.

For instance, I might tag a question that asks about how to implement queues using linked lists as

> [data-structures](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures) [lists](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists) [linked-lists](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-lists) [queues](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/queues)

If it's more about the algorithm, I might add [algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms). If there's an analysis aspect to it, I might instead add [algorithm-analysis](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm-analysis), and maybe drop either of [lists](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists)/[linked-lists](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-lists) for [runtime-analysis](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runtime-analysis)/[space-analysis](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-analysis). As you see, it's not an exact science: when editing, I try to represent the focus or perspective of the question as well as possible. Questions I might ask are:

- How relevant is it that the lists are (single-)linked?
- Is the asker specifically interested in space costs? (The default assumption is runtime, so in that case I'd always add the tag.)
- Does the asker already have the algorithm and wants it analysed, or are they looking for an algorithm first? (Then, analysis may be better posted as separate question.)
- If it's about an analysis, is it about the worst case (sadly, the default) or [average-case](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/average-case)?

As a general rule of thumb, if I can't decide in which direction to tag, chances are that the question is too broad. If you're asking for queue implementations using *both* single- and double-linked lists and a comparative analysis of runtime and space in worst and average case -- well, we're looking at a 15-page paper, so that question will have to be split up!